# Plot Cylindirical Explosion problem across radial Line

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

The second issue is that when I introduce my collected data to the plot I get a massive mess of a line that is unreadable, the data is correct and should plot a similar line above or below the analytical, except I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, my colleague mentioned that a meshgrid and scatteredInterpolant might be useful here but I am struggling to get those to work.

```
clear all ;
close all;
clc;

referenceData = importdata('C:\Users\...\Radial.dat');
referenceData = referenceData.data;
xRef = referenceData(:,1);
rhoRef = referenceData(:,2);
uRef = referenceData(:,3);
pRef = referenceData(:,4);

%% Explosion BJ
%Pressure
%Rusanov
BJRusP = importdata('C:\Users\...\p.dat');
BJRusP = BJRusP.data;
Pressure_Rus_BJ = BJRusP(1:14093,3);
xRusBJ = BJRusP(1:14093,1);
yRusBJ = BJRusP(1:14093,2);

figure(01); hold on
plot(xRef,pRef, '-');
plot(xRusBJ, Pressure_Rus_BJ, '-')

grid on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('Pressure ')
legend('Analytical', 'Rusanov', 'location', 'northwest')
title('Pressure ');
```

where `radial.dat` is

| X | RHO | U | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.9998E+00 | 0.1250E+00 | 0.0000E+00 | 0.1000E+00 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 0.9998E+00 | 0.1250E+00 | 0.0000E+00 | 0.1000E+00 |

and `p.dat` is

| X | Y | P |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.1000E+01 | 0.0000E+00 | 0.1000E+00 |
| ... |  |  |
| -0.9066E-02 | 0.3401E-02 | 0.9958E+00 |

EDIT: the first issue has been solved, I simply reduced the axis to x = (0,1) and the remaining values would just disappear, its the mess of a line that i cannot solve,

Comment: Have you tried sorting `xRusBJ`? Matlab’s `sort` returns a second output you can use to rearrange `Pressure_Rus_BJ` and `yRusBJ` so they match the new order of `xRusBJ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab draws its plot lines between points in the order you give them, not in order across the domain of the graph. You need to sort your data to get a nice plot:

```
Pressure_Rus_BJ = BJRusP(1:14093,3);
xRusBJ = BJRusP(1:14093,1);
yRusBJ = BJRusP(1:14093,2);

[xRusBJ, I] = sort(xRusBJ);
Pressure_Rus_BJ = Pressure_Rus_BJ(I);
yRusBJ = yRusBJ(I);

figure(01); hold on
plot(xRef,pRef, '-');
plot(xRusBJ, Pressure_Rus_BJ, '-')
```